# Eclipse plugin development implementation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, pydev

I work with Eclipse and PyDev plugin.

I want to develop a plugin which adds to the main menu (where File is located), an item "my own custom menu" which contains in it another menu items. 
According to some examples, I eventually implemented it by using the extension point of `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets`.

My goal is when item of "my custom menu" is clicked, it should invoke Eclipse functionality. 
for example:
"my custom menu" has menu item called "open new pyDev project". 
When "open new pyDev project" is clicked, I want to open the pyDev project creation window that manually is opened by clicking the following Eclipse menu items: `File->new->other->PyDev->PyDev` Project.

I searched quite a lot and couldn't find the way to do it.
Does someone know how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is implement [a workbench wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/project_wizards/new_project_wizards.htm) that will add them to the set of workbench wizards; then you can add a [perspective extension](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html) to add it the the corresponding menu generically.

You have to look up the perspective ID you are using with PyDev, but this is the recommended way to add new wizard items to the corresponding menu.